# How do I pass a 2D array by reference?

Tags: c, pass-by-reference

I'm reading the pixels from a plaintext .pgm file and I dynamically allocate an array to hold the pixels once they've been read, but it seems that the data inside is lost when my `readPGM` function ends. I'm passing an `int**` into a function, where becomes a 2D array and is filled, but it loses its values after the `readPGM` function ends. I suspect that passing the `int** pixels` by reference would help, but I'm not sure how to approach the problem and would appreciate any advice.

```
#Function called from within readPGM to allocate an array
int** allocate_m(int rows, int cols){
    int **matrix;
    int i;

    matrix = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *) * rows);

    for (i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        matrix[i] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * cols);
    }
    return matrix;
}

void readPGM(char* path, char version[3], int* cols, int* rows, int* grays, int** array){
    FILE* pgm;
    int pixel;
    int count = 0;
    pgm = fopen(path,"r");

    //Reading the header of the file
    fgets(version,3,pgm);
    fscanf(pgm,"%d %d",&*cols,&*rows);
    fscanf(pgm,"%d",&*grays);

    //Allocating and filling the array of pixels
    array = allocate_m(*rows,*cols);
    while (fscanf(pgm,"%d",&pixel) == 1){
        array[count/(*cols)][count%(*cols)] = pixel;
        count++;
    }
    fclose(pgm);
}

int main(void) {
    int cols, rows, grays;
    char version[3];
    int** pixels;
    readPGM("/home/charlie/25.pgm", version, &cols, &rows, &grays, pixels);
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Corrected `readPGM` function:

```
int** readPGM(char* path, char version[3], int* pcols, int* prows, int* pgrays) {
    FILE* pgm = fopen(path,"r");
    int pixel;
    int count = 0;
    fgets(version, 3, pgm);
    fscanf(pgm, "%d %d", pcols, prows);
    fscanf(pgm, "%d" ,pgrays);

    int rows=*prows, cols=*pcols;

    int** array = allocate_m(rows,cols);

    while (fscanf(pgm,"%d",&pixel) == 1){
        array[count/cols][count%cols] = pixel;
        count++;
    }
    fclose(pgm);
    return array;
}
```

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(int) * rows * columns)` is a better way to do it

Comment: and why are you doing `&*cols`?

Comment: It modifies `cols` in the main method. It was the first way I found that worked, and haven't messed with it since. I'm pretty new to pointers.

Comment: `fscanf(pgm,"%d %d", cols, rows);` does the same thing.

Comment: note that *nothing* here is passed by reference. there is no such thing in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to get an pointer to array of arrays, you should pass `int***`. Luckily there's no need for this: you function can simply return `int**`.

Remember to handle errors.

something like that (Sorry, I did not compile it):

```
int** readPGM(char* path, char version[3], int* pcols, int* prows, int* pgrays) {
    FILE* pgm = fopen(path,"r");
    //Reading the header of the file
    fgets(version, 3, pgm);
    fscanf(pgm, "%d %d", cols, rows);
    fscanf(pgm, "%d" ,pgrays);

    int rows=*prows, cols=*pcols;
    //Allocating and filling the array of pixels
    int** array = allocate_m(rows,cols);
    if (array == NULL) {
        close(pgm); 
        return NULL;
    }

    int count;
    for (count = 0; count < rows * cols; count++) {
        int pixel;
        if (fscanf(pgm, "%d", &pixel) == 1) {
            free(array);
            array = NULL;
            break;
        }
        array[count / cols][count % cols] = pixel;
        count++;
    }
    fclose(pgm);
    return array;
}
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the help! Your answer only required a small bit of modification, and I'll update my post.